# Integral over quotient of discrete group

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Let $Y$ be a proper metric space. By a lattice we mean a discontinuous group of isometries $\Gamma$ with compact quotient $Y/\Gamma$. You may also assume that $\Gamma$ acts freely. Suppose we are given a Radon measure on $Y$ which is invariant under all isometries. Let $\phi$ be a continuous map on $Y$, invariant under all isometries. I would like to know if under these circumstances the number
$$
\frac1{\mathrm{vol}(Y/\Gamma)}\int_{Y/\Gamma}\phi(x)\,dx
$$
is independent of the choice of $\Gamma$.
If it isn't, are there canonical restrictions, under which it is?

Comment: How do you define $vol$? Are you assuming $Y$ is some homogeneous space to begin with?

Comment: @Asaf: no, we assume that there exists a Radon measure on $Y$, which is invariant under all isometries.

Comment: Still, how would you define $vol(Y/\Gamma)$ in that setting?

Comment: @Asaf: By pushing down the Radon measure. This can either be done by using a fundamental domain or by using the fact that the summation function $C_c(Y)\to C(Y/\Gamma)$ is surjective.